# Can the const reference of function return formal parameters extend the lifetime?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```
const vector<int>& getVec(const vector<int> &vec)
{
    return vec;
}
```

My function is like this and, if I call `getVec` with a temporary object, can the code be safe?

```
int main()
{
   const vector<int> &v = getVec({1,2,3,4,5});
}
```

I am running this code in g++ and Visual Studio but I get two different results:

- g++ tells me: the function's vector is the same as v and they have the same value.
- Visual Studio tells me: the function's vector has the same address as v but v.size() is only 0, not 5

Is there a standard answer for this situation? Can a `const` reference return value only refer to values that existed before the function body?

Comment: What do you mean by _"g++ tell me : the function's vector as same as v"_? `vec` and `v` shouldn't be the same. `v` is a copy of `vec` and _"Visual Studio tell me : the function's vector has the same address to v"_ shouldn't happen for the same reason.

Comment: No, it can't, this is undefined behavior. You return a reference to a temporary, not a temporary object (you don't return prvalue).

Comment: When is the temporary object deleted? Isn't it after the whole expression has ended? So in this case after `v` has been asigned `{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }`?

Comment: Parameters are destroyed at the function exit. The lifetime-extension of a temporary object can be performed only once, when the temporary object gets bound to the first reference. The temporary gets bound to the function parameter and becomes a function local object, that can't be returned by a reference.

Comment: @273K Isn't the temporary vector materialized before the function call and will hence live on through the full expression, making the copy safe? Not that it's proof of anything but g++, clang++, msvc and ICX all seem to agree on that.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I believe you are correct. The line is equivalent to `getVec(std::vector<int>{{1,2,3,4,5}})` making the vector a temporary object on caller's side. That's because the function accepts a reference and doesn't destroy anything.

Comment: How do tell the size of `v`? Debug checking is not the most reliable way. Add a print or something.

Comment: I forget the & in main function !!!

Comment: There are no lifetime extension, temporary lifetimes ends at end of full expression. `v` is dangling.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo Sorry,I forget the & in main function,There is no copy, they are all references

Comment: @Nater Then it's undefined behavior.

Comment: Even if the `v` is dangling, there is no undefined behavior in the code you are showing, since you never use `v`.

Comment: The lessons learned here may apply, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8DLHk9FIQKM

Answer (score 4):

The code as shown is well-formed and doesn't have any undefined behavior. Only if you actually use `v` later, then there will be undefined behavior.

When calling `getVec` a `const vector<int>` temporary object will be materialized and initialized with `{1,2,3,4,5}`, so that the reference in the function parameter can bind to it.

Temporary objects live (by default) until the end of the full-expression in which they are materialized (which here is the expression `getVec({1,2,3,4,5})` together with the initialization of `v`). Binding them to a reference *for the first time* may extend the lifetime (under certain additional conditions), but this specifically does not apply to references in function parameters and wouldn't really help anyway, since the reference in the function parameter itself doesn't have a longer lifetime.

So the temporary object lives long enough for `v` to bind to it, but is then after the initialization of `v` immediately destroyed.

Therefore `v` will be dangling after its initialization and actually using it will cause undefined behavior. But simply initializing it this way will not.

Comment: Does that mean that in general, a const reference can extend the life cycle of a temporary value once, but this does not work for the formal parameters of the function (if the function parameter is a const reference), so the temporary value will be destroyed immediately after V is initialized up？

Comment: @Nater The kind of reference (`const`/lvalue/rvalue) is irrelevant to the lifetime extension rules. Lifetime is extended at most once, when first binding to a reference that is _not_ a function parameter, return value, or part of `new` initialization or parenthesized aggregate initialization and if the expression between the temporary materialization and reference initialization is only one of those listed at the beginning of https://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#6. The link gives the the full lifetime extension rule as well.

Comment: A *possible* curiosity is that changing all the `vector` types to `initializer_list` removes the UB (which occurs when `v` is ***used***).

Comment: @AdrianMole No? The backing array of the `initializer_list` (and the `initializer_list` itself) would have the same lifetime as the temporary `std::vector` would.

Comment: @user17732522 Not quite. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list): *The lifetime of the underlying array is the same as any other temporary object, except that initializing an initializer_list object from the array extends the lifetime of the array exactly like binding a reference to a temporary* (Note that no copy of the underlying array is made, unlike in the case of a `std::vector`.)

Comment: @AdrianMole I don't see how that helps you. The `initializer_list` is also destroyed after the full-expression. The backing array is destroyed with it. If you mean doing everything by-value instead of by-reference, then it still doesn't work because copying the `initializer_list` doesn't extent lifetime of the backing array.

Comment: @user17732522 I'm certainly not 100% sure about it (initializer lists are funny creatures) but doesn't the `v` bind a reference to the temporary array?

Comment: @AdrianMole If `v` is of type `const std::initializer_list<int>&`, then it must bind to a `std::initializer_list` object. That object follows the exact same lifetime rules as `std::vector<int>` would. The only difference is that the `std::initializer_list` refers to a backing array internally. The rule you quote says that the lifetime of that backing array behaves as if the `std::initializer_list` object was a reference binding (immediately) to that array, i.e. the lifetime of the array is the lifetime of the `initializer_list` object except for the cases I listed in an earlier comment.

Comment: It looks like you might want to return either an object, with no reference, or a `std::unique_ptr`, a reference that will not become invalid during its lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments, it is undefined behavior. It can be seen from C++11 standard draft, section 12.2/5.

> The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary.119 The temporary to which the reference is
> bound or the temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound persists
> for the lifetime of the reference except:
>
> - A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call (5.2.2) persists until the completion of
>   the full-expression containing the call.
> - The lifetime of a temporary bound to the returned value in a function return statement (6.6.3) is not
>   extended; the temporary is destroyed at the end of the full-expression in the return statement.

As we can see, Neither function argument reference nor return reference extend the lifetime of temporary `{1,2,3,4,5}`. So in `main()` you have undefined behavior, you might end up with dangling reference.

Comment: The quote literaly says that the temporary bound by reference to the function call exists until the full expression containing the call ends. Meaning, in this case, the temporary will be destroyed after `v` copied the data. No UB here. Oh... NVM. he wrote the question wrong the first time.

Comment: @ALX23z Why should `v` "copy the data". `v` is a reference to a vector.

Comment: @AdrianMole originally it wasn't a reference. OP changed it later.